# Basic Haskell IO (IO String -> Int)?

Tags: haskell

Beginner Haskeller here. I am trying to represent the [pizza equation](http://gawker.com/how-many-pizzas-should-you-order-the-pizza-equation-wi-1697815579/+whitsongordon) with a simple command line program that takes a number of people and returns an appropriate number of pizzas to order. I know I need to convert my input (`IO String`) to an Int and then convert the result to a string using `show`. How do I `IO String -> Int`? Or am I skinning this cat all wrong?

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

pizzas :: Integral a => a -> a
pizzas x = div (x * 3) 8

main = do
    putStrLn "How many people are you going to feed?"
    arg <- getLine
    -- arg needs to IO String -> Int
    -- apply pizzas function
    -- Int -> String
    putStrLn "You will need to order " ++ string ++ " pizzas."
```

Comment: It seems you have gathered some good answers here giving you good hints. So just on a general side-track: any time you start thinking `IO foo -> bar` you should be squinting nervously. You can't (*cough, cough*) get out of IO once you're in, and that's a good thing.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... I figured Haskell works like:
`Input -> [Purely Functional Magic] -> Output` where safely gluing pure code and impure data was the whole point. Or is there simply a more idiomatic way I could have expressed this problem?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that is about right. But...you can't *really* go from `IO a` to `a`, except in a function that actually returns type `IO a`; rather, the way you do things is write a function `f x = y`, and then inside of `main` you do something like `x <- readX; putStrLn (f x)`. Here, `x` is "extracted" from `IO` and passed to your pure program (`f`), so the rest of your code can be pure. But you can only do this sort of thing inside of a function that can do IO; you can't *in general* convert `IO a` to `a`.

Comment: @Daniel Well, you can program your computation with a type like `Input -> Output`; but you need to hook that computation up to some widget that actually interacts with the world and generates a value of type `Input`, then interacts with the world in a way that displays the value of type `Output`. The collection of `IO` types do this -- and GHC has a special symbol, `main`, which kicks things off. But you can't get "out" of IO. `IO foo -> IO bar` is okay; `IO foo -> bar` where `bar` doesn't have `IO` in it doesn't have many interesting implementations.

Comment: Yeah it looks like I have a good amount to learn about binding encapsulated data. It's starting to seem like that Haskell makes hard things (refactoring code, unit testing, etc.) easy, and easy things (IO, printing multi-line, formatted strings, library management, etc.) tricky.

Comment: The easy things you mention are very easy in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using read will convert the type from a string to the appropriate type if possible

And using show will convert the integer to it's string representation

```
arg <- getLine
let num = pizzas (read arg)
putStrLn $ "You will need to order " ++ (show num) ++ " pizzas."
```

Or do this:

```
arg <- readLn :: IO Int
let num = pizzas arg
putStrLn $ "You will need to order " ++ (show num) ++ " pizzas."
```

Comment: @Daniel This answer is technically correct but the thing to understand here is that when you do `arg <- getLine`, `arg` has type `String` because the binding operation 'extracts' the value from inside the `IO` container. Then you can just `read arg` and send that as the argument to `pizzas`, at which time Haskell will infer the correct type.

Comment: I am getting: `parse error on input ‘=’` with both solutions :~/

Comment: It compiles! Thanks for the solution and the explanation.